# Use map to change values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have three datasets say

```
df1 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))
df2 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))
df3 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))
```

I want to do truncation for the variable `x`: if it is negative, it equals 0. Here is the code

```
map( list(df1,df2,df3), ~ifelse( .x$x <0, 0, .x$x))
```

But the original `df1, df2, df3` are not modified. How this modification can be imposed on the original data frames?

Answer (score 1):

In R (at least in most cases), you have to assign an object to modify it.

While in python you could directly assign to the tuple `(df1,df2,df3)`, it is unfortunately not possible in R.

Therefore, if you really want to modify the original objects, you have to do it manually:

```
df1 = ifelse(df1$x <0, 0, df1$x)
df2 = ifelse(df2$x <0, 0, df2$x)
df3 = ifelse(df3$x <0, 0, df3$x)
```

However, you can achieve something quite similar using a list:

```r
library(purrr)
set.seed(1)
N=10
df1 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))
df2 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))
df3 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))

x=list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
y=map(x, ~ifelse( .x$x <0, 0, .x$x))
y$df1
#>  [1] 0.0000000 0.1836433 0.0000000 1.5952808 0.3295078 0.0000000 0.4874291
#>  [8] 0.7383247 0.5757814 0.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Note that naming the list elements is important.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, it seems that your original code is not the thing you want. Using `ifelse()` will return a vector. If you want to apply this algorithm to several columns, you have to use other functions, such as `dplyr::mutate()`. You can learn more about it on https://dplyr.tidyverse.org.

Something like this will do:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
N=10
df1 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))
df2 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))
df3 <- data.frame( x= rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N))

clean_df = function(df){
    #use either everything() or just x, I'm not sure about what you really want
    df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse( .x<0, 0, .x))) 
}

x=list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
y=map(x, clean_df)
y$df1
#>            x         y
#> 1  0.0000000 1.5117812
#> 2  0.1836433 0.3898432
#> 3  0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 4  1.5952808 0.0000000
#> 5  0.3295078 1.1249309
#> 6  0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 7  0.4874291 0.0000000
#> 8  0.7383247 0.9438362
#> 9  0.5757814 0.8212212
#> 10 0.0000000 0.5939013
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! But ```y``` only returns the variable ```x```, I want it to return the original data frames.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lst` instead of `list` to create a named list, perform the operation with `map` and use `list2env` to change the original dataframes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

res <- map(lst(df1,df2,df3), ~.x %>% mutate(x = ifelse(x < 0, 0, x)))
#Using pmax would also give the same output
#res <- map(lst(df1,df2,df3), ~.x %>% mutate(x = pmax(x, 0)))
list2env(res, .GlobalEnv)
```